# React opening blank page after I built it

Tags: reactjs

I built my React application `npm run build` and when I try to open the index.html inside the build folder, it returns a blank page.

My navigation folder:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

...


<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
        <Route path="/benefits" exact={true} component={Benefits} />
        <Route path="/features" exact={true} component={Features} />
        <Route path="/pricing" exact={true} component={Pricing} />
        <Route path="/cases" exact={true} component={Cases} />
        <Route path="/partners" exact={true} component={Partners} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact={true} component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/signup" exact={true} component={SignUp} />
    </Switch>
</Router>

...
```

I added the `homepage` in the package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Am I missing a configuration?

Thanks

Adding more details:
I edited the App.js file to include a `<h1>Test</h1>`
The MainNavigation is the file above with the Routers.

```
import React from "react";

import MainNavigation from "./components/MainNavigation";

function App() {
  return (
      <>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <MainNavigation />
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After building, when I open the index.html, only the `TEST` is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried serving the site with the `serve` npm package?

Comment: You'll probably need to do some debugging in your browser. Does the HTML include the JS in  a script tag? If so is the request to get the JS successful? The JS is probably not going to help find the error in this case. If all of that is successful, can you print anything to the screen by bypassing react-router?

Comment: @DeanJames Could you please explain how I could do it with the server npm package?

Comment: @BrianThompson The browser returns error 400 for multiples .css files. For example: ```https://mysite/%PUBLIC_URL%/css/bootstrap.min.css```.

Comment: Is that the correct url?

Comment: @BrianThompson. Yes. I even tried to open the index.html file direct from the server.

Comment: @BrianThompson I just delete the other question. We have more details here.

Comment: We also don't really care about css for resolving this specific issue. The JS is whats important for now.

Comment: @BrianThompson It also returns error 400 for the favicon.ico. It looks like the server is not being able to convert the ```%PUBLIC_URL%``` to the correct folder

Comment: That's still not JS.. But yes I would agree that %PUBLIC_URL% does not appear to be correct which is why I asked if that was the correct URL

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes, it is the correct URL. The .JS files are being loaded just fine.

Comment: If the JS files are being loaded then I don't think the URLs for failing css are the same issue. If css really causes your entire app to be hidden then I'd be shocked. At a high level in your app add a `<h1>TEST</h1>` and see if it renders.

Comment: @BrianThompson, please look at the edits that I included in the post. It looks like the Routers are causing the issue.

Comment: Can you make a running example, it could be way too many things to try to debug in comments.

Comment: @BrianThompson I would have to add all the Routers file in the example to make it run for this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter.

I'm guessing you're serving your production build statically, maybe through a CDN service?

Using a BrowserRouter makes the CDN service not able to pinpoint the entrypoint. Using a HashRouter may fix it. It adds a hastag at the end of your serving URL though

Comment: It works to load the page!!! But the navigation is not working anymore. When I click on a link, it does not navigate to the correct page.

Comment: does the URL change at least?

Comment: When I run the application, it loads as http://mysite:3000/#/. Then, if I click, for instance, in benefits, it changes to http://mysite:3000/benefits#/ and still in the home page

Comment: It's supposed to redirect to mysite:3000/#/benefits, it should load the component if you enter the URL directly. Maybe your href values don't have slashs? i.e. "/benefits"

Comment: My href values are the same as the ```MainNavigation``` routers. For example, href="/benefits" or home page: href="/".

Comment: Try adding a basename to HashRouter. <HashRouter basname="/">

Comment: Also try to undo any changes you applied using BaseRouter. May have fiddled with the whole routing setting.

Comment: Still same issue after adding the basename. I did not do any changes using BaseRouter

Comment: I'll look more into it. I'm guessing it has to do something with history?

Comment: I'm not sure. The way I'm calling it for other pages is a simple: ```<a href="/benefits">Benefits</a>```

Comment: can you try building and serving your project? This may only happen in local environment. If this is the case we could manually handle the exception